# Where are git hooks logs?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm using this hook: https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa#file-post-receive
For some reason, it doesn't work. I'd like to know what happens and check the logs, particularly reading "echo" lines (to see what is executed), but I don't see where I can read them...
I inserted another echo line to check if everything was correctly executed:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="/home/webuser/deploy-folder"
GIT_DIR="/home/webuser/www.git"
BRANCH="master"

echo "This is an executed hook!"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/$BRANCH" ];
    then
        echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f $BRANCH
    else
        echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

My question is not why my hook was not working (FYI it was due to a permission misconfig inside the "objects" subfolder).
My question here is: where do the "echo" lines go?

Comment: please add to the question the location of the remote repo and this file, and the output of `git push` - if there is no output, the hook is either in the wrong place, not executable or otherwise not being used.

Comment: Actually my problem is not why the post receive is not working (I had it working now, it was a question of permissions inside the "objects" subfolder.
My question is WHERE do the "echo" lines print.

Comment: my request still stands (to make a complete question, because in the output of `git push` is where you'd see that) but if you already found the solution please write an answer, or accept one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `githooks(5)`, "Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to git send-pack on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the user"

So if you are running `git push` from an interactive terminal, you should see the output of echo on your terminal.  If you want to store them in a file, you need to redirect stdout to a file.  Or retrieve the data from the terminal buffer.  (eg, in the tmux pane history).

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm using Atom to push, and it seems I don't get the messages...
I may look into Atom documentation then.